# Removing constraints in an Olympiad inequality

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Consider the following problem from the Indian National Mathematical Olympiad:

> Let $1<a_1\leq \dots\leq a_n$ be positive numbers such that $a_1+a_2 +\dots+a_n=2n$. Prove that  $$a_1+a_1a_2+\dots +a_1a_2\dots a_{n-1}+2\leq a_1a_2\dots a_n$$

The official solution of this problem is a little too devious for me: it involves the observation that $a_1\dots a_{n-1}(a_n-1)+ a_1\dots a_{n-2}(a_{n-1}-1)+\dots=a_1\dots a_n-1$.

I was trying to solve the problem in a more standard way: by removing the constraints in the question one after the other.

We can see that the average of the numbers is $2$, and then $a_i=2$, we have equality. Hence, what we need to see that when the numbers deviate from this average, there will be an inequality. So let $a_i=2+s_i$, where $\sum s_i=0$. However, there are still some constraints here:

1. $-1<s$
2. We should have the terms in our expressions be positive in order for us to use the various inequalities taught to Olympiad participants. Here, the $s_i$'s can be negative (and $s_1$ is definitely non-positive)
3. We have $s_1\leq s_2\leq\dots \leq s_n$.

I suppose we can remove (1) by making $s_i=-1+b_i$. This also removes the second constraint, as now $b_i>0$. However, the third constraint is still present. This is because we still have $b_1\leq b_2\leq\dots\leq b_n$. Also, we have $\frac{\sum b_i}{n}=1$.

I tried removing some more constraints, like making $a_i=1+c_1+\dots+c_i$, where all the $c_i$'s are positive, but there is still the constraint that $c_1<1$.

Is there any way to remove all constraints in this problem?

Comment: Can you clean up the $...$ in the inequality, and the solution too? E.g. do you mean $ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (\prod_{j=1}^i a_j) $? Do you really want $a_{n-1}(a_{n-1}-1)$?

Comment: @CalvinLin- I cleaned it up a little